# Find highest count totals via PIVOT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a large dataset wherein I need to count "Yes" responses for each question.  My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE (question1) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question1
, SUM(CASE (question2) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question2
, SUM(CASE (question3) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question3
, SUM(CASE (question4) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question4
, SUM(CASE (question5) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question5
...... ( + dozens more ) ...
FROM myTable
```

This gives me a table like this:

```
question1 | question2 | question3 | question4 | question5 | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
346       | 187       | 240       | 256       | 261       | ...
```

Fine. But I need to find the highest 3 values in this row.  I've researched the PIVOT function in an attempt to transform my table to look like this:

```
name      | value
--------------------
question1 | 346
question2 | 187 
question3 | 240
question4 | 256
question5 | 261
```

but I frankly don't understand how the FOR ... IN section of the example code works, and moreover, how I'm supposed to list a column "that contains values that will become column headers", as the documentation explains:

```
PIVOT
(
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)
FOR
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],
    ... [last pivoted column])
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

Since I have a table with only 1 row, I don't have a column that will become column headers. Can anyone help me understand how to this works with my 1 row dataset - or better yet, a different way of approaching this?  I feel like I may be missing something simpler.  Again, the end goal is to find the 3 questions with the highest totals.

Comment: please put some mock table and rows.

Comment: Man, I guess with a unpivot and after a select top 3 with order by value desc, will resolve your problem.

Comment: Well, you need to `UNPIVOT` actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `PIVOT`, you need to use `UNPIVOT` if you want to get those results. There are other ways to do this too, for instance, you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  SUM(CASE (question1) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question1
        , SUM(CASE (question2) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question2
        , SUM(CASE (question3) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question3
        , SUM(CASE (question4) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question4
        , SUM(CASE (question5) WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as question5
        ...... ( + dozens more ) ...
FROM myTable
)
SELECT x.[name], x.Value
FROM CTE t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        ('question1', t.question1),
        ('question2', t.question2),
        ....
        ('questionN', t.questionN)
) x ([name], Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help you:

```
CREATE TABLE #X(ID INT IDENTITY,question1 INT,question2 INT,question3 INT ,question4 INT ,question5 INT)


INSERT INTO #X
select 346,187,240,256,261  


select top 3 *
from (
select 
id,
question,
[value]
from #X
unpivot([value]  for question in(question1,question2,question3,question4,question5))P
)X 
order by [value] desc
```